# Understanding many to many relationships

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

im trying map an One to Many relationship, but i have many problems.
I have the below entity-relationship model:

[image]

So, im write the next annotations in the Usuario doctrine model:

```
class Usuario implements UserInterface{
     // Some code...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UsuarioComunicacion", mappedBy="usuario")
     */
   protected $contacto;

    // More code...
}
```

And in the UsuarioComunicacion model (the N-N table):

```
class UsuarioComunicacion{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="idusuario", type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Usuario", inversedBy="contacto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idusuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")
     */
    protected $usuario;

    // More code...
}
```

But, when im try use this relations (into controller code), Symfony says:

> "Notice: Undefined index: usuario in
>   /var/www/AppsManantiales/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 1575"

I dont have much experience mapping...and i dont know what happening.
Any ideas ?
Thanks !

**UPDATE 1**

The problem appear when i try get the contact values of an user with:

```
$user->getContacto();
```

The getContacto() is an autogenerated getter:

```
/**
 * Get contacto
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getContacto()
{
    return $this->contacto;
}
```

Comment: try changing mappedBy="usuario" to mappedBy="Usuario"and it should work

Comment: @Satya thnaks for reply, and not work :(

Answer (score 1):

The `inversedBy` in your `UsuarioComunicacion` class should be `inversedBy="contacto"` since this is the variables name.

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-many situation here. The additional table cannot hide that. This case requires some additional work that isn't as easy as adding a few ORM statements.

In the following I have only added the primary key properties as the rest should be very easy to obtain.

From the information you have given, this is the most useful approach. Let me know if it works.

Usuario:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="idusuario", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $idusuario;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    // some code
    $this->hasMany('Tipocommunicacion as Tipocommunicacions', array(
        'local' => 'idusuario',
        'foreign' => 'idtipocommunicacion',
        'refClass' => 'UsuarioTipcommunicacion'
    ));

}
```

Tipocommunicacion:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="idtipocommunicacion", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $idtipocommunicacion;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    // some code
    $this->hasMany('Usuario as Usuarios', array(
        'local' => 'idtipocommunicacion',
        'foreign' => 'idusuario',
        'refClass' => 'UsuarioTipocommunicacion'
    ));
}
```

UsuarioTipocommunicacion:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="idusuario", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $idusuario;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="idtipocommunicacion", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $idtipocommunicacion;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="valor", type="string")
 */
private $valor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. For some reason with the `@ORM\Column(...)` annotation (in UsuarioComunicacion) the relation not works.
So, i remove the annotation and rename the instance variable:

```
class UsuarioComunicacion{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Usuario", inversedBy="contacto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idusuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")
     */
    protected $idusuario;

    // More code...
}

class Usuario implements UserInterface{
     // Some code...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UsuarioComunicacion", mappedBy="idusuario")
     */
   protected $contacto;

    // More code...
}
```

Thanks for your time !